# Prove identity related to nths root of unity

Tags: complex-analysis

If $1=z_0,z_1,...,z_{n-1}$ are nth roots of unity, prove that
$$(z-z_1)(z-z_2)...(z-z_{n-1})=1+z+z^2+...+z^{n-1}$$

I don't know what is meant by the condition given. If I substitute $1=z_0,z_1,...,z_{n-1}$, isn't it become
$$(z-1)^{n-1}=1+z+z^2+...+z^{n-1}$$

Does this holds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the equation

$$z^n-1=0$$

The roots of this equation are the $n^{th}$ roots of unity, which let's say are 1,$z_1$,$z_2$,...,$\, z_{n-1}$. Then the expression on the LHS can be rewritten as the product of its factors:

$$(z-1)(z-z_1)(z-z_2)...(z-z_{n-1})=z^n-1$$

Taking $(z-1)$ to RHS,

$$(z-z_1)(z-z_2)...(z-z_{n-1})={z^n-1 \over z-1}$$

Notice that the RHS has now become the sum of the geometric series $1+z+z^2+$...

Which proves the result

$$(z-z_1)(z-z_2)...(z-z_{n-1})=1+z+z^2+z^3+...+z^{n-1}$$

You cannot substitute 1 for all the $n$ roots. Only one root can be one and the rest are complex, excluding -1.

Answer (score 1):

You know that your roots are the solutions of $z^n-1=0$, hence
$$z^n-1=(z-z_0)(z-z_1)(z-z_2)...(z-z_{n-1})=(z-1)(z-z_1)(z-z_2)...(z-z_{n-1})$$
Now you just have to divide by $z-1$
$$\frac{z^n-1}{z-1}=(z-z_1)(z-z_2)...(z-z_{n-1})$$
but the l.h.s. is the partial sum of the geometric series, i.e. $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}z^k$, hence
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}z^k=(z-z_1)(z-z_2)...(z-z_{n-1})\ .$$

If you don't know the result on the geometric series you can compute the ratio directly or try to proove it.

Comment: You don't have to invoke the geometric series: $$1-x^n=(1-x)(1+x+x^2+\dots+x^{n-1})$$ is a well-known factorisation identity. Actually the formula for the geometric series is *deduced* from this one.